# Removing individual markers from map at the end of animation

Tags: javascript, animation, leaflet, dom-events

I have a map with several moving markers on it and have been trying to remove each individual one when their respective animation ends. I am using Leaflet and Leaflet's plugin `Leaflet.MovingMarker`. I tried using methods `isEnded()` and `end` without much success.

With the latter method (`end`), the following code removes only but one marker (full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/132/)):

```
marker.on('end', function() {
  map.removeLayer(this);
  });
```

With a `click` event instead of an `end` event, each marker is made easily removable, but then this is not what I am looking for:

```
marker.on('click', function() {
  map.removeLayer(this);
  });
```

With the method `isEnded()`, have not had any luck at all either (full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/133/)):

```
var ended = marker.isEnded(); 
  
  if (ended = true) {
  console.log("this marker ended!");
  map.removeLayer(this);
  }
```

I wonder what I am missing here? Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Tried using _isRunning()_ with _setInterval_, at no avail either. Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/145/). I am guessing that the problem resides in my unability to select each one of the markers individually (as when one clicks each one of them).

Comment: Your problem is related to closures inside of loops with a delayed accessor, as detailed at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake). Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to fix your code to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will look into it!